# How to speed up `ReplaceRepeated` `//.`?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, replacement

I have to replace all the elements smaller than 0 in a large matrix to 0.But i found the speed is really slow when the matrix is big. Here is my code.
`a=RandomReal[NormalDistribution[],{1000,1000}];
AbsoluteTiming[a//. {{aa___, i_, bb___} /; i < 0 -> {aa, 0., bb}};]` Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some (much much faster) alternatives:

```
a = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {1000, 1000}];
Clip[a, {0, Infinity}]
a /. q_ /; q < 0 -> 0.
Ramp[a]
% == %% == %%%
(* True *)
```

(the last one is untested, because I'm using v.10)

Comment: Thanks i have though  an idea :`panduan[i] := Piecewise[{i, i > 0}]; Attributes[panduan] = Listable;`

Comment: @xinpei Indeed, your idea is equivalent to the `Ramp` approach. Nice! (although I believe you are missing a pair of brackets: `Piecewise[{{i, i > 0}}]`)

Comment: ...your code is better and i have wirte wrong code

Comment: @xinpei No problem, you were on the right track :-) I'm glad I could help, cheers!

Comment: (+1) for `Ramp`.